Should I be concerned about this bent stud?
As you can see in the picture, this stud in my basement is bent from the middle at least 3 inches to the left. It was screwed to the drywall that it pulled through. What can I do to stop more bending or breaking of this stud or the next one?


Have the screws or nails along the edge of the drywall in that stud been pulled right out the edge of drywall?

Wood warps/bends.  The better studs do it less.  Replacing or adding another stud there is possible, if wanted.  It probably does not be a need/must do job.  The problem with warp studs is usually hitting them with screws for drywall.

it should probably be a double stud in that location

@MichaelKaras it does look like there are slots in the edge of the drywall where the screws pulled out sideways.

@MichaelKaras, yes, it was screwed to the drywall that it pulled through.

It should be plumbed, straightened and blocked. That wall appears to carry the doubled rim joist along the stairwell, which in turn carries the common joists intersecting it.
If, however, there are obvious posts just out of view supporting that rim, the wall's probably not load bearing.
Regardless, I'd want it fixed. It's easy enough to do:

Attach a temporary lumber brace to the wall, horizontally and centered on the wall's height. Fasten it to several studs to the right. Leave the end over the end stud unattached.

Put a long straightedge on the stud, centered on its height if it's shorter than the stud.

Flex the stud into position and fasten it to the temporary brace.

Now move any other studs that have shifted (or that you simply want to adjust). Note that they're probably screwed through the drywall, so you risk damaging that finish with any movement.

Once all studs are in their final position, fit 2x4 blocks, set horizontally,  in each cavity at about mid-height. Stagger them vertically so you can face nail each one. Use pairs of 3" nails or screws to secure them.

Re-fasten the edge of the drywall if desired. You could do this with construction adhesive if you don't want new screw heads showing. Press it overnight while the glue sets.


|  |                |  |                |  |                |  |
|  |________________|  |                |  |________________|  |
|  |________________|  |________________|  |________________|  |
|  |                |  |________________|  |                |  |
|  |                |  |                |  |                |  |


Yes, there are more posts. Here is another photo with all studs https://imgur.com/a/5ws9tyH

Sorry, not posts, I was thinking of studs.
